# In Relative Clause, can Relative Pronoun come before the pronoun/noun being referred to?

Tags: grammar-identification, relative-clause, relative-pronoun, grammar-style

I came across this interesting sentence:

> Gehen Sie ebenfalls **denen** aus dem Weg, **die** stets mit ihrem Wissen angeben und **die** Sie genauso verunsichern.

Unless I'm mistaken, the **denen** here is supposed to refer to the two **die**s, which come after. In English, to my knowledge, this is not possible because it can cause readers to wonder what the relative pronoun is referring to (if they don't continue reading). But in German language, this can be.

Is my assumption correct?

Comment: You got it wrong. The two *die*s are relative pronouns while *denen* is a demonstrative pronoun that those relative pronouns refer to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grammatically, it's the other way around, the relative pronouns "die" refer to the demonstrative pronoun "denen".

However, semantically, you are completely right: "denen" is no more than a stand-in for a set of people who are later fully defined by the two relative clauses.

You could even say that "denen" is just a lazy replacement for the more accurate "denjenigen" here.

You can translate this to English quite literally:

> Also steer clear of *those* *who* constantly show off their knowledge and who ...

Comment: The answer is clear and correct but I still wonder why *denen* is lazy or *denjenigen* more accurate.

Comment: @DavidVogt You have a point there. I meant that *denjenigen* only has this one meaning, to stand in for what can be expected to be defined later, while *jenen* is just your standard demonstrative pronoun that could also refer to a group of people that has been mentioned earlier, and it doesn't necessarily create the expectation of a later definition. In a given context that's probably seldom a cause of confusion though.

Comment: It would be great if they just used "den Leute", then everything would be crystal-clear. But here, when I encounter "denen", I **immediately** think: "Heh, what is this referred to?".